# How to use flutter to perform ICMP ping

Tags: flutter

I would like to check network devices in LAN if they are alive (from a smartphone). Since there is no standard port that's always open I would like to use "ping". But for Flutter I could not find any hint.

Tried Flutter package ping_discover_network, which is only for scanning ports.

For mDNS I am not sure, if this is running by default on all Windows machines and if this would cover my use case.

Comment: I don't request for ready made code, I need an idea on how to resolve all network devices in a LAN with dart / flutter. The only way I found was to scan for ports, but you never know which ports are open on a device beforehand. ICMP ping would be perfect, but I couldn't find any way to use it with dart.